# Facebook Live Video Api - LiveVideo not avaible to everyone

Tags: facebook-live-api

I'm using php to use the facebook live api, I can start the live and I can see the stream but other users can't.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Here's the code that I'm using.

```
<?php
#print_r($_GET);
$token = $_GET['token'];
$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stream = $_GET['stream'];
system("echo $id > /tmp/id_fb");
system("echo $token > /tmp/token_fb");

$id     = file_get_contents("/tmp/id_fb");
$token  = file_get_contents("/tmp/token_fb"); 
    $id = trim($id);
    $token=trim($token);
    echo "Token:".$token."<br/>";
   echo "Id: ".$id."<br/>";

    include ("fb.php");
   //echo $token;
    $linkData = [
    'description' => 'teste',
    'title'     => "$stream",

    ];

try {
    $response = $fb->post("/$id/live_videos", $linkData, $token);


}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$video = $response->getDecodedBody();
print_r($video);
print_r($video);
$vid = $video['id'];
$rtmp_url = $video['stream_url'];
echo "A url rtmp:";
echo "$rtmp_url";
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `What am I missing?` A [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying alot of stuff, i just found out that my app on facebook wasn't public. That was the issue, hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I could not figure out why my videos weren't public, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't specify the **privacy** of your **live-video** so that it is visible to all.